# The expression "by my checks the bet should be winning" is correct?

Tags: meaning

Could you please tell me is the expressions "by my checks the match finished" and "by my checks the bet should be winning" are correct?

Many thanks,

Sandy.

Comment: Those are not correct, but I'm not sure I can help until I understand better what you're trying to say. What is "by my checks" supposed to mean? It sounds a bit like "by my count" or "by my estimation," which are informal ways of saying that one has counted or estimated something and arrived at the stated result. Also, what do you mean by "the bet should be winning"? Are you talking about a bet (wager) that appears to have a high probability or winning?

Comment: A bet-lottery bet fro example.

I've checked the results, and it should be winning.  -By my checks the bet should be winning.

Comment: Hm--there are a number of oddities in your usage there. First, lotteries aren't typically referred to as "bets"; instead, you might refer to a "lottery ticket" that you've purchased, or to the specific "lottery number" on that ticket. Second, it's unusual and arguably incorrect to refer to something that you *know* to be true--in this case, that a particular lottery ticket has the winning number on it--as something that *should* be true. So you would just say "this ticket has won," or "I have the winning lottery number," or "my lottery ticket has the winning number."

Comment: Third, "be winning" is a really odd construction; if you're using the verb "win" with "should," what you're really saying is that you *expect* a victory, not that you've *witnessed* a victory, and the proper construction would be "should win," e.g., "our team has the best players, so we *should win* the game."

Comment: Alternatively, if you just want to use "win" in the present tense (without "should"), you can say "[something] is winning," which would generally refer to a game in which [something] has the advantage (and might therefore be expected to win), or "[something] wins," which is the typical way of *announcing* that a victory has just occurred.

Comment: So if I were to rephrase your original two examples, I'd say "The match finished" (or, if for some reason you really wanted to emphasize that you personally went to go see if the match was over, "I just checked, and the match is over") and "I just checked the winning numbers, and my ticket won!", respectively.

Comment: Hi. The example:"I just checked" can be a solution. In a betting company, a ticked is referred to as a bet.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Those are not correct.

New answer based on the discussion below:

My understanding is that the original sentence "by my checks the bet should be winning" is spoken by a help-line operator for a company that sells lottery tickets. In this case it appears that the entire sentence needs to be re-thought. "By my checks..." is supposed to mean the speaker checked the company's records. "The bet should be winning" is supposed to mean that the lottery number for which the customer bought a ticket matches a winning number.

So, to rephrase the sentence, one needs to decide more carefully what to focus on. Some possibilities:

- "I've just checked our [or "the company's"] records, and it looks like your number was in fact the winning number." (The focus is on what action you just performed on the customer's behalf, i.e., checking the company's records.)
- "Our records indicate that your number should have won." (The focus is on the fact that the company's records appear to confirm the customer's complaint.)
- "Yes, it looks to me like that should have been a winning bet." (The focus is on the fact that the customer service representative and the customer are in agreement.)

Hope that helps.

---

Original long answer:
I would probably rephrase the original examples from the question as follows:

- **"The match is finished"** instead of "by my checks the match finished"
- **"I just checked the winning numbers, and my ticket won"** instead of "by my checks the bet should be winning" (I am assuming here that "the bet" in your original sentence refers to the speaker's own lottery ticket)

Explanation/discussion:

- "By my checks" sounds like it might be inspired by the phrases "by my count" and "by my estimation," which are informal ways of saying that one has counted or estimated something and arrived at the stated result. But since, in your case, you're talking about something that is easily verifiable and which the speaker has verified, it doesn't really make sense (especially in the first case) to explicitly qualify the statement.
- Lotteries aren't typically referred to as "bets"; instead, you might refer to a "lottery ticket" that you've purchased, or to the specific "lottery number" on that ticket.
- It's unusual and arguably incorrect to refer to something that you *know* to be true--in this case, that a particular lottery ticket has the winning number on it--as something that *should* be true. "Should" indicates some kind of uncertainty. (Its meaning/usage is a bit more complex than that, but that's beside the point for now.)
- "Be winning" is a really odd construction; if you're using the verb "win" with "should," what you're really saying is that you *expect* a victory, not that you've *witnessed* a victory, and the proper construction would be "should win," e.g., "our team has the best players, so we should win the game." Alternatively, if you just want to use "win" in the present tense (without "should"), you can say "[something] is winning," which would generally refer to a game in which [something] has the advantage (and might therefore be expected to win), or "[something] wins," which is the typical way of announcing that a victory has just occurred.

Comment: :) Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: :) Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. Let me explain. I'm working in a betting company, where all tickets are referred to as bets(lottery, footfall). The client calls me and he says that he's bets should be winning, while he receives the message loosing. I check the information on websites, the selections he made, and I send an e-mail to the responsible department. I write :"By my checks the bet should be winning, could you also check, and let me know if I'm right or not, if possible, explain your answer."

Comment: You can also write "according to my checks". I wanted to know if the expression:"by my checks" was incorrect.

Comment: Oh, wow, I completely misunderstood what you wanted to say. "Should" really is a very crucial word here! I'll put some thought into it and rewrite my answer accordingly.

Comment: @sandy Okay, I've added a couple of complete from-the-ground-up rewordings.